# Создать в ручную primary_key в одной таблице в sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Есть БД с двумя `primary_key` в колонках `project_id` и `endpoint`. Мне нужно поменять местами  `primary_key` между двумя колонками

```
class ProjectEndpointPermission(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'project_endpoint_permission'

     project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'), primary_key=True)
     project = db.relationship("Project", backref=db.backref("permissions",
                               lazy="dynamic", cascade='all, delete, delete-orphan'))
     endpoint = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
     group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'))
     group = db.relationship("Group", backref=db.backref("endpoints",
                             uselist=False, cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan"))
```

В файле модели я удалил `primary_key` с одной колонки и ставил в другую. Сделал миграцию, но она не увидела изменений :

```
project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('project.id'))
group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Миграцию я делал при помощи `python manage.py db migrate`.
Я ипользую `MySQL`.

В файле миграции я вручную сделал миграцию:

```
def upgrade():
     ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
     op.drop_constraint(None, 'project_endpoint_permission', type_='primary')
     op.create_primary_key(None, 'project_endpoint_permission', ['group_id','endpoint' ])
     ### end Alembic commands ###

def downgrade():
     ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
     op.drop_constraint(None, 'project_endpoint_permission', type_='primary')
     op.create_primary_key(None, 'project_endpoint_permission', ['project_id', 'endpoint'])
     ### end Alembic commands ##
```

Но когда я запускаю `upgrade` я получаю ошибку:
`op.drop_constraint('primary', 'project_endpoint_permission', type_='primary')
 File "<string>", line 8, in drop_constraint
 File "<string>", line 3, in drop_constraint`
`sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1025, 'Error on rename of \'.\\dashboard\\#sql-b50_6d\' to \'.\\dashboard\\project_endpoint_permission\' (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")') [SQL: 'ALTER TABLE project_endpoint
_permission DROP PRIMARY KEY ']`

Помогите мне переписать `primary key` в колонках одной таблици.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте по ходу скрипта миграции (upgrade) выполнить инструкции типа
создания дополнительной колонки, записи ключей в нее, навешивания на неё флага primary, а следом удаления первой primary_key-колонки

Чтобы общаться с сессией (делать миграции данных и т.д.) по ходу скрипта миграции можно использовать

```
conn = op.get_bind()
Session = sa.orm.sessionmaker()
session = Session(bind=conn)

session.add(instance)
session.flush()
```